# Interactive-Canvas load Js file so Slowly?

Tags: canvas, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, interactive

I'm working with Interactive-Canvas of Google Console. But data load from JS file load so slow. 
I have to reload the app to load.[image]
What are the causes ? What is the remedy ?

Comment: I haven't seen this problem, and it is difficult to diagnose what you might be running into based on just your description. You may want to update your question with more information including the code you're using for the canvas, if you're seeing this using the test console and, if you are, timing information from Chrome.

Comment: Yep, the interative canvas is very slow to download anything, idk why, but you can try using less dinamic files, and try load everything on begining

Comment: The Google Nest Hub are so badly too